# Using two cells inside other in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have few types of cell in table view and sometimes, for some field, these types are merged in one cell. For instance, I have cells for date and for simple text input, but sometimes those cells can be merged in one like here :

[image]

If any chance I can use `UITableView` standard pool for reusing this cells (inside one that include them).
My concern is when I get 3 cell inside `tableView:cellAtIndexPath:` (compound cell, date and text cell). When compound cell will be released table view will reuse date and text cell too? How tableView knows if it's use cell or not?

I know it can be done with custom layout for `UICollectionView`, but I want to know is that feasible for `UITableView`

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to use 3 different types of cells, you should dequeue the one you want based on some logic that uses the indexPath. The table view will reuse or create the cells as needed.

Comment: rdelmar, my question about what if that cell will use other cell `contentView` subview as its own subview. Will table view know that I use both cells, or it will think that I use one one that I return explicitly?